# What ways are there to end a reduction to a character's hit point maximum?

Tags: dnd-5e, hit-points

As a DM, I've been using a [Mummy](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/mummy), and as a result, the character of one of my players has had their hit point maximum reduced a lot. In my head, it was clear that the character would go to the nearest town and ask the priest to heal them; the priest can cast [*remove curse*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/remove-curse) to halt the bleeding and [*greater restoration*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/greater-restoration) to end the effect reducing their hit point maximum. However, they only removed the curse (by spell swapping at a level up) and went on.

So I might throw another way to get their hit point maximum on the road, but what? Besides *greater restoration* (and *wish*), what are the other ways of ending a reduction to someone's hit point maximum, especially at level 4-5?

Answer (score 14):

**In your specific situation, *remove curse* is sufficient; *greater restoration* is not needed.**

According to the description of the [mummy](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/mummy)'s Rotting Fist attack, a [*remove curse*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/remove-curse) spell is sufficient to undo the curse inflicted by Rotting Fist. This includes the reduction to maximum HP.

However, other monsters, such as the [clay golem](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/clay-golem) with its Slam attack, are capable of reducing a character's maximum HP. In the case of the clay golem, "a [*greater restoration*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/greater-restoration) spell or other magic" is needed to reverse the max HP reduction.

The spell *greater restoration* is the only thing I am aware of in D&D 5e that is specifically stated to end an effect that reduces a creature's maximum HP. But both the mummy's and the clay golem's descriptions allow for "other magic" to restore the reduction as well. **The phrase "or other magic" means that DMs should use their discretion in deciding alternate ways of restoring the max HP reduction.**

In a game I run, a PC's max HP was reduced by a clay golem. After the character had suffered the effects of the reduction for a few sessions, I decided that a [*potion of vitality*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/potion-of-vitality) would be appropriate thematically for restoring his max HP, despite the fact that the potion's description does not state that it does this. I placed one in the possession of a boss enemy for the characters to find upon defeating it, and they eventually did.

Comment: Special mention for [*aura of life*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/aura-of-life) (PHB, p. 216), which prevents a nonhostile creature in the aura from having its hit point maximum reduced while in the aura... Though I don't think it applies retroactively to existing reductions - it just prevents further reductions: "Each nonhostile creature in the aura (including you) has resistance to necrotic damage, and its hit point maximum can’t be reduced."